# Do meal bonuses affect class points from Amiibo?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3, amiibo

When scanning an Amiibo in Xenoblade 3, there is a chance to get Class Points as a reward. If I eat a meal that has a CP Boost effect (such as Erythia Sashimi Plate), will it affect the Class Points I get from scanning an Amiibo?